# Postman could not get any response but wireshark captures packet

Tags: postman, response, wireshark

I got a response on browser but postman doesn't.

Hardware Engineer create web server on the device and I was supposed to get 'ok' response when I access that with address like 192.168.4.1:8080

When I try that on chrome browser, I got ok and status 200 response. But when I do the same thing on postman, I don't get any response.

So, I used wireshark and it recognized there was the response packet like below.

```
HTTP1.1 200 OK
server: ~~
Content-Type:text/html
Connection:close
Content-Length:ld
```

I don't know why postman couldn't get any response. I've tried change settings like SSL certificate off, timeout 0, proxy off things. but it doesn't work.

Actually the thing that I want to do eventually is upload a file from mobile phone to the device and getting response for success callback.

It works on android, but not ios.

I think there are something in common android and browser, but ios and postman.

Comment: You'd better change the username to english nickname. and set the profile image.

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that response's wrong header was the problem.
After changing content-lenght from ld to number at the server side, it does work well even on the postman and ios.
I don't know why it was ok with chrome though.
Thanks.